# Filling a matrix sequentially using for loop in R

Tags: r, loops

Here's a problem with looping that I can't quite get right.

I want each row of the matrix (w) to be repeatedly filled in matrix (mat) for time "d". matrix (run) is just so I can check that my loops are running correctly by recording the values run through matrix (w).

---

here's my coding now:

```
x<-c(0,0,0,0)
y<-c(0,0,0,0)
z<-c(10,50,100,150)
a<-8
b<-4
d<-5

w<-cbind(x,y,z)

run<-matrix(0, ncol=3, nrow=d, byrow=T)
for(h in 1:d){

  mat<-matrix(0, ncol=3, nrow=a, byrow=T)
  for(j in 1:a){
    for(i in 1:b){
      mat[j,]<- w[i,]
    }
  }
  run[h,]<-mat[1,]
}
```

---

there's definitely something wrong with the way I'm filling in matrix (mat) because I'm inputting the same value repeatedly instead of sequentially. What should the correct syntax be in this situation?

---

edit: sorry, to clarify. I want to run my loop 5 times, and for each run, create a matrix (mat) (see below) filled with subsequent rows of matrix (w).

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   0   0   10
2   0   0   10
3   0   0   10
4   0   0   10
5   0   0   10
```

```
    V1  V2  V3
1   0   0   50
2   0   0   50
3   0   0   50
4   0   0   50
5   0   0   50
```

etc etc...

Comment: `w[rep(1:nrow(w), each = d), ]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create a list of matrices:

```
lapply(1:nrow(w), function(x) w[rep(x, each = d), ])


# [[1]]
#      x y  z
# [1,] 0 0 10
# [2,] 0 0 10
# [3,] 0 0 10
# [4,] 0 0 10
# [5,] 0 0 10
# 
# ... 
#
# [[4]]
#      x y   z
# [1,] 0 0 150
# [2,] 0 0 150
# [3,] 0 0 150
# [4,] 0 0 150
# [5,] 0 0 150
```

Comment: I was hoping to be able to do it using looping, but I think I'll have to revise my thinking. Sorry for another question, but how should I save each output as a seperate matrix? As.matrix gives me a list instead.

Comment: A list is a better way to save them, but if you want to save each matrix under a new variable name, you can access them as `mat[[1]], mat[[2]]`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
    mat <-  do.call("rbind", lapply(1:nrow(w), function(x) matrix(rep(w[x,],d), nrow=d, byrow=T)))
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
 [1,]    0    0   10
 [2,]    0    0   10
 [3,]    0    0   10
 [4,]    0    0   10
 [5,]    0    0   10
 [6,]    0    0   50
 [7,]    0    0   50
 [8,]    0    0   50
 [9,]    0    0   50
[10,]    0    0   50
[11,]    0    0  100
[12,]    0    0  100
[13,]    0    0  100
[14,]    0    0  100
[15,]    0    0  100
[16,]    0    0  150
[17,]    0    0  150
[18,]    0    0  150
[19,]    0    0  150
[20,]    0    0  150
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's very close to what I needed, except I would like 'mat' to have 5 rows of the same value (w[i,]) and be recreated for each run 'd'. Please see my edit for my example

Comment: So, the `mat` in my answer repeated 5 times?

Comment: 5 'mat's each containing repeats of the same line. So basically your 'mat' cut into 4 smaller matrices.

Comment: see @Henrik's answer below.